# removing a file in remote repo using a single command

Tags: git, github

Normally when we want to remove a file from remote repo, we remove the file locally, add it to staging, committing and pushing to the remote repo.
But I want to remove a file from my remote repo using a single command in local repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
`git rm file_you_want_remove`

After that, push all the changes to your remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub…

1. Login.
2. Maybe fulfill two-factor authentication.
3. Click the file you want to delete.
4. Click the bin symbol `Delete this file`.
5. Click `Commit changes`.

Probably slower than…

1. `git rm <FILE>`
2. `git commit -am "lolcats"`
3. `git push`